# Send result of ajax to my fullCalendar events

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, fullcalendar

Sorry if this is a repetitive question, but I have researched a lot here and I have not found the answer according to the programming languages ​​that I am using.

I want to pass the result of my AJAX to events of Fullcalendar. I hope the code is understood:

I will only put this file because the other is giving me good result as you can see.

**calendar.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function getJSON(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/calendario.ajax.php',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            rs = JSON.stringify(data);
            return rs;
            console.log(rs);

        }
    });
}


    $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
        header:{
            left: 'today,prev,next,Miboton',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        customButtons:{
            Miboton:{
                text: 'Boton 1',
                click:function(){
                    // alert('Accion del boton');
                }
            }
        },
        dayClick:function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            //alert('Valor seleccionado'+ date.format());
            //  alert('Vista seleccionado'+ view.name);
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
            $('#modalCalendario').modal();

        },

        events: getJSON(),
        eventClick:function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#tituloEvento').html(calEvent.title);
            $('#descripcionEvento').html(calEvent.descripcion);

            $('#modalCalendario').modal();
        }


    });
});
```

As you can see, in the property **events** I am trying to get the result of the function **getJSON()**, which brings the result JSON from AJAX.

The console.log is given me this: [image: Result of JSON]

As you can see, this result in the console I get it when I call **getJSON()** on the property **events** of FullCalendar.js.

I found this curious because I have copied this JSON and pasted in **events** and it gives me good results, but when I put **getJSON()** does nothing. What I am missing?

Have a good rest of the day!

Comment: You can call `getJSON()` outside the fullcalender code and then save that response in a variable and use the variable instead for events property like `events: myVar,`

Comment: You can just write `events: "ajax/calendario.ajax.php"` in the fullCalendar config and forget about the rest of the code. Then fullCalendar will organise the AJAX request for you automatically. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed for details of this feature.

Comment: P.s your original code wasn't working because a) Ajax is asynchronous so you can't directly return from an Ajax success call and b) even if that wasn't a problem, it makes no sense to stringify the object that jQuery just parsed from JSON for you. You'd just be turning it back into JSON text again, but fullCalendar would expect the JS array, not the JSON text.